# c++ ListView - Cannot insert new items after using ListView_DeleteAllItems

Tags: c++, listview, winapi, mfc

I have a ListView control with 4 columns that is initialized in the WM_CREATE proc.

```
        hListView1 = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, WC_LISTVIEW, NULL, WS_CHILD|WS_VSCROLL|WS_HSCROLL|WS_VISIBLE|LVS_REPORT|LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS, 230, 20, 300, 250, hwnd, (HMENU)ID_EDIT1, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
        ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyle(hListView1, LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT | LVS_EX_HEADERDRAGDROP);
            lvCol.mask = LVCF_FMT | LVCF_WIDTH | LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_SUBITEM;
        lvCol.fmt = LVCFMT_LEFT;

        lvCol.iSubItem=0;
        lvCol.cx=30;
        lvCol.pszText="";
        ListView_InsertColumn(hListView1, 0, &lvCol);

        lvCol.iSubItem=1;
        lvCol.cx=150;
        lvCol.pszText="Name";
        ListView_InsertColumn(hListView1, 1, &lvCol);

        lvCol.iSubItem=2;
        lvCol.cx=50;
        lvCol.pszText="Size";
        ListView_InsertColumn(hListView1, 2, &lvCol);

        lvCol.iSubItem=3;
        lvCol.cx=80;
        lvCol.pszText="Modified";
        ListView_InsertColumn(hListView1, 3, &lvCol);
```

Then i have a function that will insert the items (it works fine until i call deleteallitems)

```
...
LVITEM lvItem;
j = 0;
while(FindNextFile(hFind,&FindFileData)){
lvItem.iItem = j;
        lvItem.iImage = 1;
        if(FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY){
            lvItem.iImage = 0;
        }
        ListView_InsertItem(hListView1, &lvItem);
        ListView_SetItemText(hListView1, j, 1, FindFileData.cFileName);
        ListView_SetItemText(hListView1, j, 2, msg1);
        ListView_SetItemText(hListView1, j, 3, msg2);
        j++;
}
```

But then whenever i call

```
ListView_DeleteAllItems(hListView1);
```

if after i call my function that insert items, my listview is cleared (the columns are still there) but no new items are insered.. 
I heard about indexes that are not cleared but i couldnt figured it out.

Thanks in advance ;-)

Solution : 
Added

```
    lvItem.mask = LVIF_IMAGE | LVIF_STATE;
lvItem.state = 0;
lvItem.stateMask = 0;
lvItem.iSubItem = 0;
```

Comment: Have your `LVITEM` properly initialized. Apart from `.iItem` and `.iImage` you are leaving garbage there when you pass it to `_InsertItem`.

Comment: thanks Roman, that was the problem, LVITEM was not correctly initialized. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting `lvItem.mask`, so `ListView_InsertItem` doesn't know which fields are valid and which aren't.

Try something like this:

```
...
LVITEM lvItem;
lvItem.mask = LVIF_IMAGE | LVIF_DI_SETITEM;
j = 0;
...
```

Comment: added 
 lvItem.mask = LVIF_IMAGE | LVIF_STATE;
 lvItem.state = 0;
 lvItem.stateMask = 0;
 lvItem.iSubItem = 0;
Thank you :-)